# Replace column with HASH

Tags: bash, csv, awk, hash, cygwin

I have a CSV file that contain Null value in the 3rd column. I need to update this column with the hash of the second column.

Here a sample code:

```
#!/bin/bash 
declare key='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP123456'
awk -F"," '{$3 = $2"$key";print}' C:/test.csv > C:/output.csv
```

and here my sample CSV

```
A,B,?
B,D,?
F,jk,?
```

the output of my code is not correct and i didn't get Key value but Key variable name

```
A,B,key
B,D,key
F,jk,key
```

Can you please help to concat key value with the second column then apply a hash (md5 for example )

**Main question is how to apply Hash within AWK.**

thanks in advance

Comment: check how to declare variable in `awk`

Comment: Thanks PS, can I use MD5 inside awk too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
awk -F "," -v env_var="$key" '{
        tmp="echo -n "$2env_var" | openssl md5 | cut -f2 -d\" \""
    tmp | getline cksum
    $3=cksum
    print
    }'
```